# Default timestamp is not working with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
Model 
 date: {
      type: Number,
      default: timestamp
    },


let user = await UserModel.findOne({decider_id});

    if(user){
      user.decider_id = decider_id;
      user.user_id.indexOf(selfID) === -1 ? user.user_id.push(selfID) : console.log('Do nothing');
      await user.save();
    } else {
      let user = new UserModel({ decider_id, user_id: [selfID] });
      await user.save();
    }
```

On adding timestamp is working but in updating i guess it does update when some changes found but when nothing changes found it does not change the timestamp value but i want to update timestamp all the time when i commannd it

Comment: Any one who can help me on this ?

Comment: Why don't you use javascript new Date().getTime() method ?

Comment: Can you please help me how can I make this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add use javascript getTime method. Hope this will help you !

```
let user = await UserModel.findOne({ decider_id });

if (user) {
  user.decider_id = decider_id;
  user.user_id.indexOf(selfID) === -1 ? user.user_id.push(selfID) : console.log('Do nothing');
  user.date = new Date().getTime();
  await user.save();
} else {
  let user = new UserModel({ decider_id, user_id: [selfID], date: new Date().getTime()  });
  await user.save();
}
```

Comment: Yeah this will help me as well.